# BytesIO readline method returns bytes although there is no newline b"\n"

Tags: python, byte, buffer, readline, bytesio

I am using **readline** method from BytesIO API. Expecting to get empty bytes but the method always returns whatever the buffer contains.

```
b = io.BytesIO()
b.write(b"foo")  # Note that there is not newline \n
b.seek(0)  # Move to beginning of buffer
b.readline()
```

Returns:

```
b'foo'
```

Instead, I would expect:

```
b''
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect `b''`: can you elaborate?

Comment: According to docs: 


" readline (size=- 1, /)

Read and return one line from the stream. If size is specified, at most size bytes will be read.

The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text files, the newline argument to open() can be used to select the line terminator(s) recognized."

I would assume that if there is no line terminator, the method returns empty bytes.

Comment: I read that as: in this case there's only one line (the whole data).

Comment: OK it can be ambiguous. Perhaps they could update the documentation to be more explicit.